# Why does ''tst'' in Geburtstag sound like ''ts'',but not like ''tsh''

Tags: pronunciation

I used FORVO to get right pronounciation and heard ''ts''.
How do i know when letters are consonant combinations and when they are not?

Comment: Why would it sound like 'sh'?

Comment: While everybody's right that in this case this is due to the Fugen-s, the underlying rule is much simpler: _st_ can become _ʃt_ only at the beginning of a syllable. And syllables don't spread over word boundaries: _Ge-burts-tag_.

Comment: If in doubt, you can look the syllables up in DWDS (or any good dictionary) under Worttrennung. Also, without the jargon, look at how the word breaks down; it's referring to a day -- Tag, so that's its own syllable. (There is a word Stag, in German, something to do with the rigging in a sailing ship. In the highly unlikely event someone was born up there then you might conceivably have a Geburt-stag with the s pronounced ʃ. I'm fairly certain this has never occurred though.)

Answer (score 4):

This is a connection-"s" which connects "Geburt" and "Tag". It's always spoken as "s" and not "sh". You can find it in many other compound nouns.

Comment: Maybe that "s" is actually an ancient genitive artifact but this is just a fast idea.

Answer (score 4):

Some compound words in German include a so called "Fugen-s", which is an s that is added to the end of the first word. Unfortunately there is no rule for that.

Geburt is such a word that gains an extra s in compounds, so it becomes Geburts- +word. This is pronounced as ts, as those two letters belong together.

Possible compounds are

> Geburts+kalender
> Geburts+urkunde
> Geburts+tag

This should clarify, why there is no sht-sound.